# Internal Server Error on localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

This message appeared when I open [localhost/phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin)

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit, Apache 2.4 64-bit with FCGI module, PHP 5.6.10 NTS 32-bit, and Guard Loader for PHP 5.6.

Thank you..

Comment: Check your error logs for a more definitive error message.

Comment: `[Wed Jan 11 22:21:33.837641 2017] [fcgid:warn] [pid 4000:tid 744] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : [client ::1:49826] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error`
`[Wed Jan 11 22:21:33.837641 2017] [core:error] [pid 4000:tid 744] [client ::1:49826] End of script output before headers: index.php` <-- this is what the error logs says

Comment: It turns out because of `zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support=3` line in php.ini after I erased the line, the next problem is "The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration"

Comment: solved the whole problem and now it's running! thanks